# How to make the 3 boxes to display above the background image

Tags: html, css

How to make the boxes display above the background images. I tried to use z-index bit it doesnt work.

[image] 
HTML

```
<section class="showcase">
</section>
<section class="boxes">
     <div class="box 1">          
     </div>
     <div class="box 1">          
     </div>
     <div class="box 1">          
     </div>
</section>
```

Section "showcase" contains the background image.
I set the margin of .boxes -40px.

Comment: Please can you show us your code, what you've tried and be a bit more specific?

Comment: _I want..._ Is not a question.

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: Could you add some CSS as well, please? Looking at the image it seems the boxes are above the background image but maybe the background color of them is missing? It's just speculation ...

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no CSS I and just by looking at the image I assume the issue is with the background color of the boxes.

Here is a working example with what I assume the CSS is:

```css
.showcase {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 200px;
}

.boxes {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: -40px;
}

.box {
  border: 2px solid salmon;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: calc((100% / 3) - 30px);
  height: 100px;
  background-color: cadetblue;
}
```

```html
<section class="showcase">
</section>
<section class="boxes">
     <div class="box 1">          
     </div>
     <div class="box 1">          
     </div>
     <div class="box 1">          
     </div>
</section>
```

And a link to a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x75p9mj0/

Please provide more code (relevant CSS) so we can better see what could the issue be.